# ComboBox Not Dropping Down List of Items

Tags: combobox, telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I am using a Kendo ComboBox in my app and defined the markup of the control as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox().Name("GroupUserName")
    .Placeholder("- Select Group -")
    .Suggest(true)
    .BindTo(
        (Model.Groups ?? new[] { Model.Group })
            .Select(i => new { i.GroupName, i.GroupUserName })
    )
    .DataTextField("GroupName")
    .DataValueField("GroupUserName"))
```

I know that there are 2 records being bound in the BindTo method, and these are being passed to the client component.

```
jQuery(
  function(){
    jQuery("#GroupUserName").kendoComboBox({"dataSource":   
       [{"GroupName":"membershipgroup01","GroupUserName":"membershipgroup01"},
       {"GroupName":"publicgroup01","GroupUserName":"publicgroup01"}]
       ,"dataTextField":"GroupName","dataValueField":"GroupUserName",
       "placeholder":"- Select Group -","suggest":true
     });
});
```

However, the combobox, when I hit the drop down, doesn't show anything.  There is no drop down to allow me to select a value.  See this image:

[image: ComboBox not showing drop down]

There is no drop down that appears when you click the drop down selector.  Why?

I'm using JQuery 1.8.2, along with the kendo.all and kendo.aspnetmvc scripts...

Comment: are there any JS errors in the console?

Comment: I did not get an error...

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am experiencing similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to an anonymous type without field names. Kendo doesn't have anything to grab because the objects you told it to bind to don't have fields named `GroupName` and `GroupUserName`.

From what it looks like, you shouldn't need to bind to an anonymous type at all. So this:

```
.BindTo(
    (Model.Groups ?? new[] { Model.Group })
            .Select(i => new { i.GroupName, i.GroupUserName })
)
```

Should be:

```
.BindTo(
    (Model.Groups ?? new[] { Model.Group })
)
```

If for some reason you do need to bind to an anonymous type you can give the fields the appropriate names:

```
.BindTo(
    (Model.Groups ?? new[] { Model.Group })
            .Select(i => new { GroupName = i.GroupName, GroupUserName = i.GroupUserName })
)
```

Comment: If it didn't have field names, why are the names appearing in the JSON: `{"GroupName":"publicgroup01","GroupUserName":"publicgroup01"}`.  So it's inferring the field names from the source.  I'll give it a shot, but I think I did that and experienced the same problem.

Comment: When you say `.Select(i => new { i.GroupName, i.GroupUserName })` it is creating a **whole new object** with the _values_ of `i.GroupName` and `i.GroupUserName`, not the names of the field. Yes, the names are in the Model you are passing, but not in the new object you are binding to. Does that make sense?

Comment: it's not helping, still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was a conflict between JQuery UI and Kendo UI. When I removed references to JQuery UI, it worked.